# Meaning of 人 in Japanese internet slang

Tags: kanji, internet-slang

In a page from the [Dead Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Tube) manga, a man is being killed during a live video. Some of the viewers comment the scene simply with "人". What is the meaning of this kanji when used in this way? Could its graphical aspect remind of clapping or praying hands? [Here's the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo6Ic.jpg) in question (look at the second panel). Thank for your help!

Comment: It probably symbolizes praying hands. At least I've encountered emojis like: (人･∀･) or (ﾟ∀ﾟ人) in which case the writer asks for something (お願い). It could also be a very abstract version of this: （／_＼） (怖い）

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`人` represents two hands pressed together. It appears in [many kaomoji](https://kaomojinavi.net/kaomoji/n/namu.htm). In this context it represents [praying hands (合掌)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1jali_Mudr%C4%81), a traditional Buddhism/Shinto praying gesture. It can also mean more casual ["please"](https://kaomojinavi.net/kaomoji/o/onegai.htm).

Comment: Emoji  versus 人 kanji

Comment: @naruto Thank you for your answer! So, in the context of the manga it represents a prayer for the person that is being killed, right? Could it be considered similar to rip/rest in peace?

Comment: @Marco Yes, although this gesture is not that common like in some other Asian countries, Japanese people do this in funerals. Look up with 焼香.